# Is there a way to count the number of items in values of a dictionary corresponding to a key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I would like to come up with a fix that makes my code find the average of the values corresponding to a key in dictionary.

Here is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        name, *line = input().split()
        scores = list(map(float, line))
        student_marks[name] = scores
    query_name = input()    
    li=[sum(value)/len(student_marks.keys()) for key,value in student_marks.items() if key==query_name] # PROBLEM HERE
    print(format(li[0],'.2f'),end='')
```

The only key to solve my puzzle here to figure out a way to get the count of items in the values part of the dictionary.Unfortunately doing `len(student_marks)` or `len(student_marks.keys())` won't sail my ship.

I am trying to make use of list comprehension to do this, although it can be done easily in more than one line but I am practicing to get better at list comprehensions.Any answers in line of list comprehension approach to solve this will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: I tried count() but didn't work out for me

Comment: Are you trying to find the avg per key, or the total avg?

Comment: Average for the particular key.

Comment: I just need a way to count the number of values that match the key from my if condition.

Comment: is it possible to have multiple values for a single key ?@DeepSpace

Comment: @AbbasEbadian Generally no. But I was thinking about the same thing, what if it does?

Comment: @AbbasEbadian No, each key in a dictionary can have a single value. That value however may be anything (list, set, custom object, etc)

Comment: @DeepSpace so the dict assumed in this question is kind of  unreachable unless value of each key is a list.

Comment: @AbbasEbadian It is pretty obvious that this is the case here. `scores = list(map(float, line)) ; student_marks[name] = scores`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comprehension divides the `sum` by the number of keys in the entire dictionary (`student_marks.keys()`) but for calculating the average of a single keys' values the number of keys is irrelevant. A valid solution using a comprehension would be

```
print([sum(marks) / len(marks) for name, marks in student_marks.items()
       if name == query_name][0])
```

### But

You don't need the `for` nor the comprehension. The whole point of using a dictionary is that you get direct access to individual keys.

```
n = int(input())
student_marks = {}
for _ in range(n):
    name, *line = input().split()
    scores = list(map(float, line))
    student_marks[name] = scores
query_name = input()

# the only line you need is this:
print(sum(student_marks[query_name]) / len(student_marks[query_name]))
```

Then

```
>> 1
>> a 1 2 3
>> a
2.0
```

A standard lib alternative:

```
from statistics import mean

...

print(mean(student_marks[query_name]))

>> 1
>> a 1 2 3
>> a
2.0
```

Comment: Your solution is efficient and works. I am going to mark it as accepted. But again if there were to be a fix to my list comprehension approach can it be done, just out of curiosity?

Comment: @Sagittarius009 I updated the answer with an explanation